# play framework migration from 2.0.8 to 2.1.0 Dynamic form cannot find symbol

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, migration, playframework-2.1

I have migrated play framework from 2.0.8 to 2.1.0 and i have followed this [guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration21)

but i am getting error **cannot find symbol** while using dynamic form.

here is my code:

> final DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();

```
                        ^cannot find symbol
```

I have also import : import play.data.Form;

anyone has idea about what i am missing during migration?

EDIT: here is my build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.github.play2war.plugin._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {val appName         = "Lndlabproject"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"  % "4.0.3",
  "japid42" % "japid42_2.9.1" % "0.5.3",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
  "com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
  "org.apache.ant" % "ant-jsch" % "1.7.1",
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean
)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(

    Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*)
    .settings(Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "2.5")
    .settings(

  // Add your own project settings here      
  ebeanEnabled := false, 
  resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Play Repository", url("http://branaway.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),

  resolvers += Resolver.url("play-easymail (release)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),resolvers += Resolver.url("play-easymail (snapshot)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)}
```

EDIT:

> resolved issue by moving javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean dependencies upwards.

like

```
 val appDependencies = Seq(
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"  % "4.0.3",
  "japid42" % "japid42_2.9.1" % "0.5.3",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
  "com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
  "org.apache.ant" % "ant-jsch" % "1.7.1",

)
```

Comment: Have you done a clean and recompiled it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Play 2.1 migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration21).

> play.mvc.Controller.form() renamed to play.data.Form.form() Also
>   related to modularization, the play.data package and its dependencies
>   were moved out from play core to javaCore artifact. As a consequence
>   of this, play.mvc.Controller#form was moved to play.data.Form#form

So do `DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();` and also

In your **build.scala**(i.e. shown by you in comments below) `javaCore` dependencies are at the end

```
 val appDependencies = Seq( 

"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18", 

"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final", 

"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.0.3",

 "japid42" % "japid42_2.9.1" % "0.5.3", 

"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8", "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9", 

"com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT", 

"org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4", 

"org.apache.ant" % "ant-jsch" % "1.7.1", 

javaCore, 

javaJdbc, 

javaEbean

   )
```

Maybe javaCore dependencies are not able to load so move `javaCore,javaJdbc,javaEbean` to the top

```
val appDependencies = Seq( 

javaCore, 

javaJdbc, 

javaEbean,

"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18", 

"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final", 

"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.0.3",

 "japid42" % "japid42_2.9.1" % "0.5.3", 

"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8", "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9", 

"com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT", 

"org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4", 

"org.apache.ant" % "ant-jsch" % "1.7.1"

   )
```

and then do

```
play clean
play ~run
```

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund try removing final and have you imported  `import play.data.DynamicForm;`

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund post your build.properties and plugin.sbt

Comment: build.properties `sbt.version=0.12.2`

Comment: plugin.sbt `// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Play2war plugins release" at "http://repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.0.2")
`

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund that looks fine post your build.sbt I think you are missing javaCore dependency in it.

Comment: we don't have build.sbt in play 2.1.0, i think

Comment: you mean to say build.scala?

Comment: Damn! i cant post full build.scala, but you can check my dependencies

Comment: `val appDependencies = Seq(
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
      "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"  % "4.0.3",
      "japid42" % "japid42_2.9.1" % "0.5.3",
      "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8",
      "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
      "com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
      "org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
      "org.apache.ant" % "ant-jsch" % "1.7.1",
      javaCore,
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean
    )
`

Comment: why are you posting in comments post full build.scala in you question

Comment: @singakash thank you so much, just resolved the issue. check out the edited versio. thanks alot

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund if my suggesion helped you then you should accept my answer I am posting the solution in my answer so other can see the solution

Answer (score 0):

Replace with:

```
Form.form().bindFromRequest();
```

`form()` is a static method, thus you need a static import or code as above.